# Angular universal not working on the production server

Tags: angular, typescript, express, server-side-rendering

I have created a rest api application with express framework and on client site I used angular universal. I have tested it on my local machine and everything was fine.

[[image: 1]]

After I add my application to my server it was not working as I expected. 
The server is running and the client as well.

After page refresh the data will be shortly displayed on the site and in the browser debug console I will see:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksEaL.png)

I used curl to check if my rest api server is reachable and it is working fine.

> curl localhost:3000/getData

Did someone the same experience?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "universal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run universal:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.9",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mqtt": "*",
    "ng2-mqtt": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "semantic-ui-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "window": "^4.2.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.9",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "jsdom": "11.3.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}


{
  "name": "restapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node app.ts",
    "start": "nodemon ./dist/app.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.17",
    "mosca": "^2.8.3",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.1.5",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.11.0"
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

**I find out that the port 3000 was not free. I used sudo ufw allow 3000. I am using Ubuntu as distribution.**

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots of short chunks of text (like your debug console message), but instead copy and paste the relevant bits into your question.

Comment: may be a cors problem

Comment: I am using within my express framework https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors but the data is shortly rendering and then it is not working anymore. The request crashs or something like that

Comment: did you resolved your issue?